# Need help with implementing BlendarTrack recording into blender

Tags: animation, add-on

I used the BlendarTrack app to record a session with the intention of using the camera tracking data in an animation that I plan to make. The problem I'm having is, no matter what I do, it appears to not show anything besides a black screen. What do I do? (Btw, I am extremely new to blender so I'm sure I might have skipped at least 10 steps, but I do have the 3d model and the camera set up in the right spot).

Comment: First question: What on earth do you mean by "a session of blenderartrack"? https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JohnEason blendartrack -if you give it a search you can get a quick answer ... But I agree we can't help with a question asked this way

Comment: The creator of the Blendartrack app says (in response to another user having a similar issue to yourself) that you can feel free to send questions to hello@cgtinker.com

Comment: Ah ok. A third-party addon in that case, not part of Blender.